# Onenote Graph API removes styles and data-tags on table replace

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I have an OneNote page with table of tasks: First column is a task name with to-do tag (checkbox), and second column with description. The table has been created from OneNote web UI (OneNote online).

I want to mark tasks completed via Graph API. [According documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote_update_page#supported-elements-and-actions) I can update table content only by replacing whole table. But after update my table does not have borders anymore, and all to-do tags (checkboxes) are missing.

Workflow:

1. Get page content ([docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote-get-content#page-html-content), [response](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-content-html))
2. Take table from content, find required task, replace `data-tag` from `to-do` to `to-do:completed`
3. Get page content with generated IDs ([docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote-get-content#page-html-content), [response](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-content-includeids-html)) to find target table id
4. Send PATCH request to replace the table ([request](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-patch-content-curl) - [response](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-patch-content-response))
5. [Table became replaced](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-updated-content-html) but all border has been set to `0px`, and all `data-tags` has been removed

Here is a formatted value of content field of PATCH request payload ([raw request here](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/18ce26e1c977af51ec870c098594033c#file-patch-content-curl)):

```
<table style="border:1px solid;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid"><span style="font-weight:bold">Task</span></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid"><span style="font-weight:bold">Comment</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid"><span data-tag="to-do:completed">Update todo in table</span></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid">There are some issues when we updating todos located inside of tables</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is wrong with my PATCH request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575442.aspx) at the bottom the Example block of HTML has info about how the OneNote-API handles tables.
Specifically borders will be hidden or displayed depending on the current setting for the page under "Table Tools" -> "Layout" -> "Hide Borders" toggle.
In terms of to-do boxes these have to be wrapped in a paragraph, for example:

```
 <td><p data-tag="to-do:completed" data-id="oa">OA Check</p></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. Replacing `<span data-tag...` with `<p data-tag...` has made the thing. But when I get page content after update, API returns spans again. This is very confusing. But I believe I just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not specify border in the style attribute. Just specify the border as the table cell attribute.

And thanks for using the OneNote APIs via Microsoft Graph!

Comment: It works. And it means that [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/onenote_input_output_html#tables) is wrong

Comment: I have submitted issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3229